# jQuery selector add a string ,but selected get undefined value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

As the code below, they actually have 5 school drop-down and 5 departments drop-down list. So, it'll have five id, which is `school_1`,`school_2`,`school_3`...so on. The options are all same in these five school drop-down, same value, same text.

The department drop-down(`id="dept_x"`) would show different departments list which belongs to the school that I selected in school drop-down list.

The `school_1`connect with `dept_1` ,and `school_2`connect with `dept_2` and ...so on.

Now, I have a problem with getting value in selected. The code `var school_code = $("#school_" + num).val();` in the jQuery. I always get value `undefined`.

if I use selector `"#school_1` or `"#school_2` or other else, instead of  `"#school_" + num` ,then it would work perfectly. It all do the same thing, so I choose to use for loop.

How do I fix this? or other better way?

Thank you so much!

The example HTML:

```
<select id="school_1" name="school_1" class="form-control">
    <option value="1001">school-A</option>
    <option value="1002">school-B</option>
    <option value="1003">school-C</option>
    <option value="1004">school-D</option>
</select>

<select id="dept_1" name="dept_1" class="form-control"></select>
```

The jQuery:

```
var school_num = '5';   //the value 5 is comes from a php variable and it's a string.
for(var num = 1; num <= parseInt(school_num); num++){

    num = String(num);
    //console.log("#school_" + num);

    $("#school_" + num).change(function(){
    $("#dept_" + num + " > option").remove();

        var school_code = $("#school_" + num).val();
        console.log(school_code);

        //then doing ajax to get department data in the database.

    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you @freedomn-m, @Satpal and @Rory McCrossan, your answer all works. I'll use a common class instead of a for loop. That actually is a great idea, I've never thought that way. Also, the `.change()`. Sorry, I didn't notice that `change()` would after the loop. Just check to document again. I've learned a lot today. Thanks again guys. :)

Comment: You should consider accepting the answer, which helped you the most. See [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Yes, cause all good answer, it's difficult to decide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a closure to ensure the `num` value within the `change` event handler is what you expect it to be, and not the last value in the array - as the `for` loop will have finished *long* before any `change` event has fired.

```
var school_num = '5';
for(var num = 1; num <= parseInt(school_num, 10); num++){
    (function(num) {
        $("#school_" + num).change(function(){
            $("#dept_" + num + " > option").remove();
            var school_code = $("#school_" + num).val();

            //then doing ajax to get department data in the database.
       });  
    })(num)
}
```

That being said you can massively improve the logic by using common classes and a single event handler. You can then use DOM traversal from the first `select` to find the related `select`. This will completely remove the need for the loop. Try this:

```js
$('.school').change(function() {
  var $dept = $(this).next('.dept').empty()
  var school_code = $(this).val();
  console.log(school_code)

  //then doing ajax to get department data in the database.
  $dept.append('<option>Foo</option>'); // just an example
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="school" name="school_1" class="form-control">
  <option value="1001">school-A</option>
  <option value="1002">school-B</option>
  <option value="1003">school-C</option>
  <option value="1004">school-D</option>
</select>

<select class="dept" name="dept_1" class="form-control"></select>

<select class="school" name="school_2" class="form-control">
  <option value="1001">school-A</option>
  <option value="1002">school-B</option>
  <option value="1003">school-C</option>
  <option value="1004">school-D</option>
</select>

<select class="dept" name="dept_2" class="form-control"></select>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to use a common class i.e. `school` to bind the `change` event handler. As store the arbitrary data in `data-*` custom attribute which can be fetched using [`.data(key)`](https://api.jquery.com/data/#data2). Additionally [`.empty()`](https://api.jquery.com/empty/) can be used to remove all child nodes.

*HTML*

```
<select name="school_1" class="form-control school" data-id="1">
    <option value="1001">school-A</option>
    <option value="1002">school-B</option>
    <option value="1003">school-C</option>
    <option value="1004">school-D</option>
</select>
```

*Script*

```
$(".school").change(function(){
    var num = $(this).data('id');
    var dept = $("#dept_" + num);

    //remove options
    dept.empty();

    var school_code = $(this).val();
    console.log(school_code);

    //then doing ajax to get department data in the database.
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Scope.

The value of your variable 'num' is read inside the `.change()` call - at that point, it will always be 5.  Consider the pseudo-code version:

- loop through each element, 1-5
- assign change handler
- end loop
- later: change handler hits - num is 5

Fix this by using `this` inside the handler:

```
var school_code = $(this).val();
```

You'll have to do something similar for dept.